# Jenkins and GIT: REJECTED_OTHER_REASON when pushing tags

Tags: git, jenkins, git-push, git-tag

I want to add a tag to my GIT repository via Jenkins and its GIT Plugin.
Therefore I configured the GIT Publisher Plugin like [this](http://www.benhallbenhall.com/2013/03/hudson-jenkins-create-git-tags-branches-automatically/):
[image]

It shoult create a tag (e.g. Tag-40) and push it to the repo. But when running this job (no other build steps) I get the following error ("REJECTED_OTHER_REASON"):
[image]

After some research it seems that this isn't working because of a detached head. Checking the Jenkins working dir results to the following:
[image]

Executing...

```
git checkout master
git push --tags
```

... in my directory is works and pushes the tags to my repo. I could add this ad command line build steps but this doesn't really solve my problem since it needs credentials manually.

Can you help me solve this problem? Do you know what I'm doing wrong or does anyone of you has a similar setup?

Thanks!